# Java - Hidden import folders in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to work off of an existing code base, and one of the files has an import statement accessing the path game.format.noFlash.*. However the format folder only has files for the other classes; the noFlash file folder is nowhere to be found.

I know it must be there because when I begin to type in the import statement in intelliJ, one of the autofill options is the noFlash folder. Is there a way to access it, and if so how?

Comment: Is it static import? In this case check the javadoc about Static Imports usage: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html

Answer (score 0):

The auto-fill options are display packages and also **class names**

I suspect the noFlash is a class and not a folder and Intellij is suggestion that you can import it, for [example](https://www.leepoint.net/language/10basics/import.html):

> Classes can be specified explicitly on import instead of using the wildcard character.
>   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  // Make a single class visible.